# How do I get the byte array from a PDF generated by pdfMake?

Tags: pdf, pdfmake

I have a web app that is creating a PDF using pdfMake.  I want to get the byte[] from the generated pdf to be used to transmit to a database.  How can I get the byte[] of the pdf generated by pdfmake?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method provided by the library to fetch the array of the generated PDF.

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBuffer(function (databuffer) {
                                    data = databuffer;      
                                });
```